# How do I search and replace multiple items on a single line?

Tags: ruby, vim, text, replace

I have a line like:

```
contact.psu_code = row[:psu_code] unless row[:psu_code].blank?
```

and I want to substitute `psu_code` with, say `contact_disposition`, like:

```
contact.contact_dispositon = row[:contact_disposition] unless row[:contact_disposition].blank?
```

where it substitutes only in the single line I'm on, with no confirmation. I know of `%s/orig/sub` but it's cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean, it's cumbersome? If you want to do a search-and-replace on a single line, you don't need to use `%`.

```
:s/psu_code/contact_disposition/g
```

Without `g`, Vim would stop after replacing a single occurrence. By specifying `g`, the replacement is done on the entire line.

If you want confirmation, add `c` to the options after `g`.

Here's a convenience function for it:

```
function! LineReplace()
    let search = expand('<cword>')
    call inputsave()
    let replacement = input('')
    call inputrestore()
    call setline(line('.'), substitute(getline('.'), search, replacement, 'g'))
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>r :call LineReplace()<CR>
```

I mapped it to `<leader>r`, but you can easily change that to whatever keymapping you'd like.

Comment: Cumbersome was probably a bad choice of words. What I would really like is a way to put my cursor on a word, issue a command where  I just type the replacement and bam! the line is substituted

Comment: @steve_gallagher: OK, that's easy enough. I wrote a very simple convenience function for this, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks, the function is very cool and above and beyond. Vim has become 70% of my life, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
%s/orig/sub/gc
```

g => global, implies multiple times on a line

c => confirm

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get this done:

1. In normal mode `:s/psu_code/contact_disposition/gc` . The last c is for confirmation, you can use it or not.
2. In visual mode: Shift-V to select the line then `:s/psu_code/contact_disposition/g`

I hope this helps